# removing appened items on browser resize with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am a newbie to jQuery and trying to append some items on browser resize, which originally changes their position in the DOM like shifting them up or down the elements for responsive design requirements. Elements append or to say changes their position receptively when I downsize the browser like < 767px but the problem I am facing is in restoring the elements to its original position and style on browser upsize, like > 768px or to say undoing the appends I have done on < 767px. I am using following code.
Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery(window).resize(function(){
 var wwindow = jQuery(window).width();
  if (wwindow < 767) {
          $( ".contact" ).after( $( ".social" ) );
          $( ".strip-right" ).prepend( $( ".ingrese" ) );
          $( ".strip-right" ).prepend( $( ".news" ) );
          $( ".contact-info .box .col3" ).after( $( ".contact-info .box .col1" ) );  
          $( ".property-list .common h4 span" ).prepend( "/&nbsp;" ); 
          $( ".clients" ).after( $( ".content-box .col2" ) );
          $( ".banner" ).before( $( ".caption2" ) ); 
          $( ".banner" ).before( $( ".caption2" ) );
          $( ".caption2 .row" ).before( $( ".caption2 .txtb h3 strong" ) );
          $( ".caption2 > strong" ).append( $( ".ref" ) );
          $( ".caption2 > strong > span" ).prepend( "|&nbsp;" );
  }
  if (wwindow > 768) {
          $( ".social" ).remove();
          $( ".ingrese" ).remove();
          $( ".news" ).remove();
          $( ".contact-info .box .col1" ).remove();
          $( "/&nbsp;" ).remove();
          $( ".content-box .col2" ).remove();
          $( ".caption2" ).remove();
  }
 });
});
```

Comment: One more thing, if I refresh the page post > 768px, it shows what I exactly need but without refreshing it doss not change the look accordingly after 768

Comment: In your code I can see in both places you are using less than symbol if (wwindow < 767) { , if (wwindow < 768) { , any mistakes there?

Comment: That was a typo :( but even if I use >768px it does nothing without the page refresh ? any ideas on how can I achieve what I want ??

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .social,.ingrese,.news,.contact-info .box .col1,.content-box .col2,.caption2{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

@ media tag is used by bootstrap like framework which is well know for its responsive deisgn. You can hide the element by just adding them like above and when your browser reached max width of 768 it will apple the css added into @media tag

Comment: Yes, you are right @dharmesh, I have done it on various instances to control the page but I don't want to overuse it, as it will require me to make more elements with the same content in the dom and hiding and displaying them with media queries. any jquery solution ??

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code below to refresh the page beyond >768px and that seems to work but takes 1 or 2 seconds to refresh the page after being resized.

```
$(window).resize( function() {
window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```